# what is meant by "service level" in docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

While going through the documentation of **[getting started with kubernetes on docker desktop](https://birthday.play-with-docker.com/kubernetes-docker-desktop/)**, i came through this word called **[service level](https://birthday.play-with-docker.com/kubernetes-docker-desktop/#:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20makes%20sure%20containers%20are%20running%20to%20keep%20your%20app%20at%20the%20service%20level)** , can anyone help me understand what is service level?

ps: i am a beginner in docker and kubernetes

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Services are used to communicate with Deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what "Service level" references in this case,

It says in your link:

> Kubernetes makes sure containers are running to keep your app at the service level you requested in the YAML file

And a little further down:

> And now remove that container:
>
> Check back on the result app in your browser at http://localhost:5001 and you’ll see it’s still working. Kubernetes saw that the container had been removed and started a replacement straight away.^

Judging from the context they refer to that the [kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-controller-manager) in the Kubernetes control plane continuously watches the state of the cluster and compares it to the desired state. When it discovers a difference (for example when a pod was removed) it fixes it by adding a new pod to match the number of replicas defined in the deployment.

For example if the deployment was configured to run in N number of replicas and one is removed, N-1 replicas remain. The kube-controller-manager starts a new pod to achieve the desired state of N replicas.

In this case the service level would refer to the number of replicas running, but as mentioned, it is ambiguous...

Answer (score 0):

There are `services` in kubernetes which you can use to expose applications (containers) running on `pods`.

You may read through this blog to learn more
https://medium.com/@naweed.rizvi/kubernetes-setup-local-cluster-with-docker-desktop-7ead3b17bf68

You can also Watch this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CX8AnwTW2Zs&t=272s